# Make 3.5 Framework DataGrid column to fit cell content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-3.5

Am using Datagrid from [WpfToolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com) for my 3.5 Net WPF project. And I faced with the problem, that when cell content has bigger Width than column, it is out of bounds and is not displayed.

[image: result]

I need column to fit maximum cell width, but I haven't found any option to do it. DataGridView in 4.0 Net framework has similar property `AutoSizeColumnsMode`, but 3.5 Net DataGrid has no. May it be fixed with using templates or I have missed some property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column fits its content if I set up `DataGridTemplateColumn`'s property `Width` to `Auto`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the DataGridColumnHeader stlye width to *:

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Width"  Value="*" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `DataGridColumnHeader` Width property is double, but not GridLength, so I can't set it to `*` value/